# Dynamic Adding of Text Fields JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, textfield

Hi I'm new to JQuery and I'm making a API Tool just like https://www.hurl.it/ 
I also want to have the Add Parameters Button and it will create a parameter name and a value field and render it inside a div. Here's my form.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'invoker', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">URI</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uri" placeholder="Enter URL">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parameters</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addParams">Add Parameter</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" id="paramArea">

       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

And here's my Script

```
$(function() {
    $("#addParams").click(function() {
        $('<input/>').attr({
            type: 'text',
            id: 'test',
            name: 'test',
            autofocus: 'true',
            class: 'form-control'
        }).appendTo('#paramArea');

        $('<input/>').attr({ 
            type: 'text', 
            id: 'paramValue', 
            name: 'paramValue', 
            autofocus: 'true', 
            class: 'form-control', 
            placeholder: 'value' 
        }).appendTo('#paramArea');
    });
});
```

It's far from what I want to accomplish. Can someone help me out? thanks

Comment: You've explained what you did very well but we don't know whats happening that is unexpected behaviour for you now ;) I can guess but rather have you put up the actual problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution of what you can do:

- Remove the id element from your input as in your case any number of items you add to the form they will have same id where as the id should be unique.
- Append the textbox to a div instead of the form.
- Here is a working [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/g1q3sc65/2/).

In this code "addText" is an id that i gave to a div element in your HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addParams").click(function() {
    $("#addText").append('<br><input type=text class="form-control" name=test value="New Element" />');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <!-- {!! Form::open(array('url'=> 'invoker', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form')) !!} -->
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">URI</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uri" placeholder="Enter URL">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Parameters</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" id="addText">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addParams">Add Parameter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- {!! Form::close() !!} -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used it and I figure out how to solve my problem. Sorry if it's been confusing. thanks anyway.